# xdebug not working on netbeans with built-in server using laravel

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug, laravel-5, php-builtin-server

I ran into an issue when trying to debug in NetBeans. I set breakpoints and click on a *Debug Project* button (Ctrl+F5), but no debug info is shown in the IDE.

Also, *phpinfo();* doesn't provide me with an *xdebug* section.

I'm using  [Laravel framework version 5.0](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0).

It has a *server.php* file, which I use in the *Run Configuration* of NetBeans IDE as a *Router script* (PHP Built-in Web Server).

The *server.php* is as follows:

```
<?php
$uri = urldecode(
parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri))
{
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```

Here is my xdebug configuration in *php.ini*:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension_ts=php_xdebug.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

I'm using *zend_extension_ts* property as long as I've downloaded a *Thread Safe* PHP package (*php-5.6.7-Win32-VC11-x64*). I tried just *zend_extension* as well.

The *php_xdebug.dll* is 2.3.2 version (a *PHP 5.6 VC11 TS (64 bit)* one).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. And solved this way.
Since I'm using PHP 5.6, my php.ini file has only the following settings for XDebug:

```
zend_extension = php_xdebug-2.3.3-5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=on
```

At NetBeans, I have:

[NetBeans' Run Configuration for PHP Built in server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLnjM.png)

Hope this help =)